# C++ multiple locks of the same mutex from different threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, c++14

I have an Android app, that uses JNI. From Java there are calls to JNI methods written in C++14. However, problem is, Java and Android are using multiple different threads that can call my JNI method concurently from different places.

Under the hood, foo and bar manipulates `std::vector`. I cannot read it in `readVector`, while is is being modified in `modifyVector`, so I need locking.

So far I use

```
std::shared_timed_mutex m;

void modifyVector() {
   std::lock_guard<std::shared_timed_mutex> lk(m);

   //do some work - writer, modify std::vector -> only one thread allowed here
}

void readVector() {
   std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> lk(m);

   //do some work - only reads from std::vector, multiple threads allowed here
}
```

Problem is, that `modifyVector` or `readVector` can be called multiple times from different Java threads and I am locking the same mutex multiple times which causes entire app to freeze often. I dont know if it is a deadlock or some other issue, but I dont know how to solve / debug this. I know that there is a recursive mutex, but I think that it will cause performance issues, since `modifyVector` and `readVector` are called very often.

I have been trying to find some tutorial or anything about this problem, but I usually find problems of type "single producer - multiple consumer" which I dont think apply to my problem.

Comment: What you're looking for is a reentrant readers-writer lock. In C++, I think this is called a recursive shared lock. Unfortunately, the standard library doesn't seem to have such a lock.

Comment: Are you locking Java threads from C++? It is highly recommended not to use inter-language multithreading with JNI.

Comment: I am locking c++ threads in jni, not java threads.

Comment: If your threads are attached to the JVM, have you tried using `MonitorEnter` and `MonitorExit`?

Comment: @Eric Havent tried, but Monitor wont allow multiple readers, will it?

Comment: @MartinPerry, unfortunately not. On another note, is there any way you can avoid recursively locking?